# form_input as only numeric in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'd like to change the type of input field from text to numbers only.I've tried as following

```
<?= form_input('num', '','class="form-control" id="num", type="number"');?>
```

but not working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this one for numeric input:

```
$data = array(
  'name' => 'num',
  'id'   => 'num',
  'class'=> 'form-control',
  'type' => 'number'
);

echo form_input($data);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$data = array(
  'name' => 'num',
  'id' => 'num',
  'class' => 'form-control',
  'type' => 'number'      //it's 'number', not 'numeric'
);

echo form_input($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass everything as an associative array, here the array index are attribute of **HTML** input tag.

```
<?= form_input(array(
  'name' => 'num',
  'class' => 'form-control',
  'type' => 'number'// input type number
));
?>
```

**more info:** http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/helpers/form_helper.html

Comment: CodeIgniter doc's are now on the official codeigniter website http://www.codeigniter.com/docs

Answer (score 0):

I find it useful to add a step parameter for currency fields.

```
echo form_input(array(
    'name' => 'estimated_cost',
    'id' => 'estimated_cost',
    'class' => 'form-control',
    'type' => 'number',
    'step' => 0.01
));
```